# Selenium ElementNotInteractableException: submit button wont work

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

i have been scraping from website since yesterday but the submit button wont work with click.

this is the code

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_btnSearch2').click()
```

this is element from the website

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf$ctl00$btnSearch2" value="Cari" onclick="SetSource(this.id);" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_btnSearch2" class="btn btn-primary" autopostback="True" style="margin-top: 31px">
```

the error

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
> (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141

website link : https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx Cari BUTTON
i hope you can understand my question!thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 time.sleep(5)
 buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='Cari']")
```

This returns 2 buttons. Choose the one you want.

`buttons[0].click()` #First button..Currency selector?

`buttons[1].click()` #Second Button..Date selector.

To check elements. Open the developer console. press CTRL+F. In the bar type the `xpath`. It will highlight the element and show how many are there with the same attribute.

Comment: thank you but it still wont work..error : type object 'By' has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: It's in the capitals. XPATH

Comment: its still the same..error : ---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
the message just blank tho

Comment: Although, it is advisable to use WebDriverWait, sometimes, it just doesn't work. I use time.sleep(x) ..then find the element with the same xpath, the regular way. `driver.find_element_by_xpath`.

Comment: so the other element has the same xpath? woah i didnt know that bcs im actually very new with scraping thing,do you mind to tell me how to check that?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    By.xpath, "//input[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_btnSearch2']"))
```

Could you try explicit wait

Comment: You are sure there is only.one element  with that locator ?

Comment: yeah..this is the link if you have time to check https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx